# Why does my review timer increase?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

Each time I review 20 questions (on "triage" for instance), I get a timer "come back in X hours".

I get the timer feature, it prevents the site from getting exclusively moderated by "whoever is online right now".

What I don't get is that every time I reach the 20 questions mark, the timer increases by 1 hour. Why does it work this way ?

Comment: Because you get faster in reviewing, and finish 20 reviews sooner every time? It has to stop though, the time period will not be over 24 hours.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your quota resets every day at UTC 00:00 (midnight in the UK at the moment).

If you see the timer increase each time you reach your quota, you are simply getting faster at reviewing; you finished earlier than the day before so there is more time to go before you reach UTC 00:00 again.